# Fortify - Source Scan

Tags: java, fortify

We ran Fortify source scan on our code. In many places it shows critical issue/violation :

> Cross-Site Scripting: Reflected - The method _jspService() in
>   WorkSheet.jsp sends unvalidated data to a web browser on line 368,
>   which can result in the browser executing malicious code.

Line number 368 is

```
subNum="<%=submissionNo%>";
```

We get **submissionNo** using :

```
String submissionNo = request.getParameter("SUBMISSIONNO");
```

Is there any way to resolve this without using JSTL or is JSTL is the only option?

Comment: Did you check this? https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29

Answer (score 0):

Look at the URL @jcoppens gave, and remember this one main rule: Perform input validation on the way in and encoding on the way out.

Look at OWASP Stinger for input and OWASP ESAPI or OWASP JEP for encoding alternatives, do not roll your own validation framework.

Do not perform input validation client-side, it's too easy to bypass.

Do not consider any data source trusted unless you can absolutely guarantee that no data could be maliciously modified.  Yes, this means your database is untrusted.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for eliminate XSS risks is always to solve the problem in the source code. To do so, you have to sanitize any user input before it is processed and/or rendered back to the browser. For example, in JSP by using JSTL `<c:out>` tag or `fn:escapeXml()` EL function when displaying user-controlled input.

If you can not perform the first solution because it has a huge cost for you, you should perform a general server input validation.

If you are using Spring MVC, Struts, Struts2, Grails or JSF, you could give a try to [HDIV](http://www.hdiv.org). It eliminates the risk of XSS for the read-only data, applying integrity validations (assures the received value is the same as the generated at server side) for the rest of the data that come from client side. For text fields included within forms (non read-only data), HDIV offers generic validations (whitelist and blacklist). In addition, it offers more features for eliminate or mitigate OWASP Top 10 risks.